# Is it possible to set background color inside Text Box in RDLC Report?

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc

I need a yellow highlight on parts of text in a generated word document. Highlighted words are meant to be changed by user after report generation. This is pretty common use case in my opinion. 
Changing font color is not a good option, because it's not clearly visible on printed document.

In the Visual studio RDLC disainer Background Color button is disabled inside the Text box and on Placeholders. 
I tried adding manually Background attributes to Style section of TextRun in RDLC. This doesn't work.
The only option I found is to break text into separate Text Boxes and set background on the whole text box. But that is a very inconvenient option for developer. And even more inconvenient for end user, because the text is generated in separate tables what makes it a hell to change.

Is there a way or workaround to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Even if you interpret HTML tags as styles you can't use background styles. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967(v=sql.100).aspx